# Error throwing when calling "call_indirect" in a function in WebAssembly module

Tags: webassembly

I got an error "**RuntimeError: function signature mismatch**" when calling the exported method "func0". So, what cause the problem?

```
(module
 (table $t 10 anyfunc)
 (elem $t (offset (i32.const 0)) $func1 $func1) 
 (memory $0 1)
 (export "memory" (memory $0))
 (export "main" (func $main))
 (export "func1" (func $func1))
 (export "func0" (func $func0))
 (func $main (; 0 ;) (result i32)
  (i32.const 42) 
 )
 (func $func0 (; 1 ;) (result i32) 
  (call_indirect (i32.const 0))   
  (i32.const 0)
 ) 
 (func $func1 (; 1 ;) (result i32)   
  (i32.const 1) 
 ) 
)
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out @YHSPY?